# Overdraw-optimize RecyclerView layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I have a `RecyclerView` that has multiple view types that all have a different rendering background-wise. Naturally I want to avoid overdraw for all these components, so I give my `RecyclerView` and all views up in the hierarchy no background at all.

This works fine as is - until I start animating items in and out. The `DefaultItemAnimator` of course nicely blends items in and out and therefor opens a "hole" in the `RecyclerView` where the background of it shortly becomes visible.

Ok, I thought, lets try something - let's give the `RecyclerView` only a background when animations are actually running, but otherwise remove the background, so scrolling works smoothly at high FPS rates. However, this is actually harder than I originally thought, since there is no specific "animations will start" and corresponding "animations will end" signal in `RecyclerView` nor the `ItemAnimator` or related classes.

What I recently tried was to combine an `AdapterDataObserver` with an `ItemAnimatorFinishedListener` like this, but without success:

```
RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener finishListener = 
    new RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationsFinished() {
            recycler.setBackgroundResource(0);
        }
    };

recycler.getAdapter().registerAdapterDataObserver(
    new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            start();
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
            start();
        }

        private void start() {
            recycler.setBackgroundResource(R.color.white);
            if (!recycler.getItemAnimator().isRunning()) {
                return;
            }
            recycler.getItemAnimator().isRunning(finishListener);
        }
    }
);
```

The issue here is that the adapter's range callbacks are ran way earlier than the actual animations run, because the animations will not be scheduled before the next `requestLayout()` happens internally in the `RecyclerView`, i.e. `recycler.getItemAnimator().isRunning()` in my `start()` method always returns `false`, so the white background is never removed.

So before I start experimenting with an additional `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` and bring that into the mix - has anybody found a proper, working (easier?!) solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I went further down the road and included a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` - this seems to be working:

```
/**
 * This is a utility class that monitors a {@link RecyclerView} for changes and temporarily
 * gives the view a background so we do not see any artifacts while items are animated in or
 * out of the view, and, at the same time prevent the overdraw that would occur when we'd
 * give the {@link RecyclerView} a permanent opaque background color.
 * <p>
 * Created by Thomas Keller <me@thomaskeller.biz> on 12.05.16.
 */
public class RecyclerBackgroundSaver {

    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    @ColorRes
    private int mBackgroundColor;

    private boolean mAdapterChanged = false;

    private ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener mGlobalLayoutListener
            = new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            // ignore layout changes until something actually changed in the adapter
            if (!mAdapterChanged) {
                return;
            }
            mRecyclerView.setBackgroundResource(mBackgroundColor);

            // if no animation is running (which should actually only be the case if
            // we change the adapter without animating anything, like complete dataset changes),
            // do not do anything either
            if (!mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().isRunning()) {
                return;
            }

            // remove this view tree observer, i.e. do not react on further layout changes for
            // one and the same dataset change and give control to the ItemAnimatorFinishedListener
            mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            mRecyclerView.getItemAnimator().isRunning(finishListener);
        }
    };

    RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener finishListener
            = new RecyclerView.ItemAnimator.ItemAnimatorFinishedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationsFinished() {
            // the animation ended, reset the adapter changed flag so the next change kicks off
            // the cycle again and add the layout change listener back
            mRecyclerView.setBackgroundResource(0);
            mAdapterChanged = false;
            mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(mGlobalLayoutListener);
        }
    };

    RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver mAdapterDataObserver = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            mAdapterChanged = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeRemoved(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            mAdapterChanged = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onItemRangeMoved(int fromPosition, int toPosition, int itemCount) {
            mAdapterChanged = true;
        }
    };


    public RecyclerBackgroundSaver(RecyclerView recyclerView, @ColorRes int backgroundColor) {
        mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        mBackgroundColor = backgroundColor;
    }

    /**
     * Enables the background saver, i.e for the next item change, the RecyclerView's background
     * will be temporarily set to the configured background color.
     */
    public void enable() {
        checkNotNull(mRecyclerView.getAdapter(), "RecyclerView has no adapter set, yet");
        mRecyclerView.getAdapter().registerAdapterDataObserver(mAdapterDataObserver);
        mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(mGlobalLayoutListener);
    }

    /**
     * Disables the background saver, i.e. for the next animation,
     * the RecyclerView's parent background will again shine through.
     */
    public void disable() {
        mRecyclerView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(mGlobalLayoutListener);
        if (mRecyclerView.getAdapter() != null) {
            mRecyclerView.getAdapter().unregisterAdapterDataObserver(mAdapterDataObserver);
        }
    }
}
```